# I cant tell if this is a conditional probability question/If so, how to solve this?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A robbery has been committed and McGruff the crime fighting dog has been called in to investigate. He discovers that Sally Coldhands was seen wearing gloves in the neighbourhood shortly after the crime, and thus he concludes that she should be arrested. From the past experience, you know that 50 percent of the people Mcgruff says should be arrested for robbery are actually guilty. Before making the arrest, you order some additional investigation. From a large population of convicted robbers, you find that 60% wore gloves at the time of the crime and continued to wear them for an interval after the crime. Further investigations reveals that 80% of the people in the neighbourhood of the crime were wearing gloves around the time of the crime.

Based of the fact Sally was wearing gloves, what is the probability that Sally actually committed the crime? Hint: Answer is 0.43

This is a long question. I cant seem to derive 0.43 as the answer. I did probability trees but answer is different. Which led me to thinking if this is some kind of conditional probability question? Even so I cant seem to derive 0.43 as the answer.

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense.  These aren't independent events, obviously, but we are given no information regarding the dependence.    You can get the $.43$ by pretending that these are independent events though...The probability that a guilty person is caught and wears gloves would then be $.5\times .6=.3$, and the probability that an innocent person is caught and wears gloves is $.5\times .8=.4$.  Thus, Bayes would tell you that the answer was $\frac{.3}{.3+.4}=.42857$.  As I say, though, I don't think this is a very sensible calculation.

Comment: thanks, and sry for a delayed reply, I just wanna know what do you mean by these cannot be independent events? How so?

Comment: You specifically say that the dog suspects her  $\it because$ she was wearing gloves.  Therefore, her wearing gloves and being suspected by the dog are not independent.

Comment: Hmm but I thought the 50% is based on whether they are guilty or not, not so much whether they are suspected. So it wouldnt really affect the outcome? And u know that the dog only suspect when they wear gloves, so technically they are just saying those who wear gloves are 50% guilty. You could exclude the dog and it would be the same bcos this dog has zero thought process. Wear gloves = suspect =50% guilty. U get rid of the suspecting part and it would still be 50%. I dont know, I may be wrong tho :)

Comment: This is a fairly silly problem, so I don't think it is worth thinking about too hard.  The dog could hardly ask that every person who was wearing gloves be arrested, so presumably there were other factors involved which we don't know about. Also, asserting that half of the glove wearing population is guilty of the crime is absurd.  But, as I say, this is all guesswork.  Final comment.

Comment: Yeah.. true thanks btw.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.